# Duda sobre el uso de fichero en Python

Tags: python

soy relativamente nuevo usando el lenguaje Python y me surgió un problema en la ejecución de un fichero. No se porque se me crea un fichero extra cuando intento abrirlo, siendo que ya había creado uno con anterioridad.
El código que escribí fue este:

```
archivo = open('tabla-n.txt','w')
archivo.write('Este es mi fichero')
archivo.close()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Cual fichero extra?

Comment: El fichero que se me crea cuando ejecuto el programa es el que el ultimo(tabla-n.txt) y el que quiero que me abra es el que esta ubicado dentro del la carpeta Ficheros(tabla-n.txt). El lugar donde ejecute el programa es tabla.py.

Comment: Borra ambos ficheros, ejecuta de nuevo y cuentanos que pasa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Muy probablemente estás ejecutando el script desde el IDE, dándole a algún tipo de botón "play".

Cuando lo haces así, la carpeta de trabajo no es la carpeta que contiene tu script, sino la carpeta raíz que tengas cargada en el IDE. Es decir, en tu caso el IDE establece la carpeta de trabajo a `PYTHON 2021` y luego ejecuta `python ./Practica/Ficheros/tabla.py`

Cuando en tu script haces `open("tabla-n.txt")` el nombre de fichero que especificas se entiende relativo a la carpeta de trabajo y no a la carpeta en que está el script, por lo que al crear el fichero lo hace en la carpeta `PYTHON 2021`.

### Solución sencilla

En lugar de ejecutar el script con el botón "play", abre una terminal (seguramente tu IDE te permita abrir una terminal integrada en el propio IDE) para situarte en la carpeta que contiene el script (`cd Practicas/Ficheros`) y desde ahí ejecutar tu programa con el comando `python tabla.py`.

De este modo la carpeta de trabajo coincidirá con la carpeta en que se halla el script.

### Solución más compleja

El script puede averiguar en qué carpeta está, haciendo uso de una variable llamada `__file__` que Python inicializa al lanzar tu script. Esa variable contiene la ruta absoluta hasta tu fichero `tabla.py`.

De esa ruta absoluta podemos quedarnos con la parte que representa la carpeta (descartando el nombre de fichero `tabla.py`) mediante la función `os.path.dirname()`

Una vez ya tenemos en qué carpeta está el script `tabla.py`, usamos esa misma carpeta como parte del nombre de fichero que queremos abrir. Así le pasamos a `open()` una ruta absoluta, y no relativa, por lo que abrirá el archivo `tabla-n.txt` que está en esa ruta.

Todo ello sería así:

```
import os
carpeta_script = os.path.dirname(__file__)
nombre_fichero = "tabla-n.txt"
ruta_absoulta = os.path.join(carpeta_script, nombre_fichero)

archivo = open(ruta_absoluta,'w')
# ... etc
```

Esta solución tiene la ventaja de que funciona con independencia de cuál sea la carpeta de trabajo en el momento de lanzar el script. Es decir, no importa desde dónde invoques `python`.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Ahora ya entiendo mucho mejor el uso del fichero.